# elmah with mvc 3 sql membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, configuration, elmah

It was really easy to install elmah with nuget and get it working right away.

The challenge came in while trying to password protect the page.

In the project I have, there is an `Admin controller` which I use mvc 3 sql membership provider which comes out of the box when u start an mvc 3 app. The default impl is not using any roles. It just validates the user, and only the authorized users can use the admin anyway.

In the elmah log :

```
<authorization>  
    <allow roles="admin" />  
    <allow roles="dev" />  
    <deny users="*" />  
</authorization>
```

how does this work? how can i define and pass these roles so elmah would understand this?

is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look like you're on the right track.  Since you trust any logged in user, you first deny anonymous user access and then allow authorized user access like this:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a Nuget package by Alexander Beletsky that makes it very easy to integrate Elmah with MVC and role-based security: [Elmah.MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC).  It works great and creates a controller that can be secured by role and allows nice routing as well.

Here is the [project page](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc.controller).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [Elfar](http://sourceforge.net/p/elfar/wiki/Home/) instead of Elmah for an MVC3 Application.  Elfar is "inspired" by Elmah, but is a lot simpler and easy to properly configure.  There's several nuget packages for it with several database types.

I find Elmah to be a lot heaver than it needs to be for somple exception handling.  Elfar is a lot simpler.